# How do you update a component again straight after an update in react

Tags: css, reactjs, dom, dom-events

So i'm trying to make a bar turn green then afterwards go back to its original color of black but it seems like it takes the later line as what it updates.

```
const [color, setColor] = useState("black")
const bubbleSort = async () => {
    const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
      let len = arr.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
              setCurrentIndex(j)
              console.log(j)
              console.log(currentIndex)
              if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                  setColor("green")
                  console.log(color)
                  document.getElementById(`bar${j + 1}`).style.backgroundColor = color
                  let tmp = arr[j];
                  arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                  arr[j + 1] = tmp;
                  setArr([...arr])
              }
              setColor("black")

              await sleep(200)
          }
          
      }
```

Comment: This should be a good read for you: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it could be easily done with an useEffect hook.

something like this...

```
const FooComponent = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("black")

  useEffect(()=> {
    if(color === "green") {
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        setColor("black");
    }, 3000); 
    }   
  }, [color, setColor])

  return <div onClick={() => setColor("green")}> HI </div>

}
```

So the useEffect works like that. Every time color changes it will run that func.

In our example, when you click the div the color will be set to green and it will run the useEffect hook that will wait for 3 seconds and than set the color back to black,